# How to get a email in a controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the email of the current session, because I'm creating a mailer, and I want to get the email in the controller and not with the form, but when I try it, I get this error:

```
undefined method `contacts' for "lajoya@gmail.com":String Did you mean? concat
```

My code is this:

```
before_action :set_enterprise

def create
   @contact = @enterprise.contacts.new(contact_params)
   ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver

   respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
end

private

def set_enterprise
  @enterprise = current_enterprise.email
end
```

**Update:**

I tried with the suggestion of alexander:

```
@contact = current_enterprise.email.contacts.new(contact_params)
```

and I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a stacktrace so we know where that error is coming from?

Comment: What is `current_enterprise`?

Comment: I update the error with a pic @IsaacBetesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the method ".contacts" on current_enterprise.email. Unless your email has a method called "contacts" rails won't know what to do. I think what you want to do is this:

```
@contact = current_enterprise.contacts.new(contact_params)
```

but you defined @enterpise as current_enterprise.email. This results in:

```
@contact = current_enterprise.email.contacts.new(contact_params)
```

You should either call current_enterprices directly or set it separately.

```
@contact = current_enterprise.contacts.new(contact_params)
```

or

```
def create    
 @contact = @enterprise_current.contacts.new(contact_params)
end

def set_enterprise
  @enterprise = current_enterprise.email
  @enterprise_current = current_enterprise
end
```

If you want to store the email of the current user, you should maybe create an email column for your users or enterprises and update the Users data instead of creating a contact record.

Comment: You copied the wrong one. Try: @contact = current_enterprise.contacts.new(contact_params)

Answer (score 0):

The final solution, that I can do it is this code:

```
@contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
@contact.email = current_enterprise.email
```